# How to removing unduplicated data?

Tags: r, duplicates, match, object-detection

I try to object detection problem in R. First data is image data(RGB). Second is bounding box information(class, coordinates...)
But some picture doesn't have bounding box information. So i check some file.  As a result, It's unnecessary. So i want to remove this data. But, for loading image file i can't remove file directory. Let's see.

```
image_all <- list.files(img_dir, pattern = "png", full.names = TRUE)
head(image_all) #And then i use magick package in r. Load and resize file.
[1] "C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/0.png"    "C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/1.png"   
[3] "C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/10.png"   "C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/100.png" 
[5] "C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/1000.png" "C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/1001.png"
> head(bbox)
# A tibble: 6 x 12
  file_name class            x1           y1           x2           y2           x3           y3           x4          y4           
  <chr>     <chr>           <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       <chr>       <int>
1 0.png     4, 4, ~  166.9801643~ 150.2190229~ 167.1537030~ 146.5573567~ 185.2927712~ 147.4170282~ 185.119232~ 151.078694~ 
2 1.png     4, 4, ~  19.29481532~ 126.6060203~ 20.46862692~ 128.2216333~ 14.06897217~ 132.8712547~ 12.8951605~ 131.255641~  
3 10.png    1, 1, ~  99.69594772~ 187.4999087~ 102.1867698~ 191.0384564~ 84.99339110~ 203.1410626~ 82.5025689~ 199.602514~    
4 100.png   4, 4, 4  100.1321271~ 63.97578214~ 102.6031447~ 64.09151524~ 102.2166042~ 72.34454343~ 99.7455865~ 72.2288103~    
5 1000.png  1, 1     205.8749899~ 136.5865980~ 211.2637429~ 142.6596224~ 170.5469358~ 178.7887077~ 165.158182~ 172.715683~     
6 1001.png  1, 1     35.37469380~ 89.71580246~ 41.00788160~ 96.06430034~ -0.40033915~ 132.8068949~ -6.0335269~ 126.458397~
```

What i want is if file_name of bbox does not exist(as compared image_all), remove image_all vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of `match/subset`. But before removing the unwanted values from `image_all`, get the file names without extension with `basename` and `sub`.

```
bn <- sub("\\..*$", "", basename(image_all))
i <- match(bbox$file_name, bn)
image_all <- image_all[i]
```

**Data**

```
image_all <- c("C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/0.png","C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/1.png",
"C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/10.png","C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/100.png",
"C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/1000.png","C:/Users/Sang won kim/Desktop/train/1001.png")
file_name <- c("0", "1", "10", "1001")
bbox <- data.frame(file_name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```